# How disable checking data integration in create statement (reference to non-existing table)

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

Let assume that I have an empty database and I want to create two tables. There is a relationship between them. For example, one of attributes (call them b) in R is a foreign key. The definition SHOULD (database is empty, I have not executed any statement, yet) look:

```
create table R(
a type primary key,
b type references S(b)
);  

create table S(
b type primary key
);
```

If I try run script with statements as above, I get error (according to line: b type references S(b)) , because S doesn't exist - that is normal and natural. It is possible to disable checking existing of tables, coresponding to foreign keys?

I know I can change order of statements. Or create tables without constraints, and add them later.

Why I'm asking. Let assume that we have many tables, with many relationships between them. Ordering tables manually will consume a lot of time, when we will want prepare kind of 'backup script'.

I know that it is possible to disable constraint as below:

```
alter table table_name disable constraint_name;
```

But that works for example with insert statement. There is a solution proper to create statement?

Comment: You can ask Oracle to defer checking whether the constraint is violated.  You cannot create a constraint that refers to a non-existent object.

Why don't you want to create the tables first (in whatever order you want) and then create the constraints?  That's normally how tools that generate DDL for multiple objects handle this out of the box.

Comment: I know that pointed solution is one of most reasonable and there are built-in mechanisms generating backup scripts. I just wanted to know whether it is possible to disable mechanism as I wrote in first post. I asked because I had a list of insert statement in random order, so that makes problem with foreign key violation (I don't ask how to order this list correctly, it's not my question).

Comment: If your problem is with the list of `INSERT` statements in random order, then it is easy enough to create deferred constraints that are not enforced until the transaction is committed.  That is very different than creating a constraint that references an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: You may be able to use the `CREATE SCHEMA` syntax for this, like in my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9090431/409172).  Then Oracle will create all the tables at one time and will resolve all the dependencies.  Although you may still need to modify the output, for example to remove semicolons.

Comment: @jonerles - thanks, I was looking for something like that.