# table or view does not exist error for unknown reason

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DROP TABLE BASIC_USER;
DROP TABLE ADMIN_USER;
DROP TABLE EQUIPMENT;
DROP TABLE CAVE;
DROP TABLE DUNGEON;
DROP TABLE ADVENTURE;
DROP TABLE AUTHOR;
DROP TABLE CHARACTER_GROUP;
DROP TABLE MY_CHARACTER;
DROP TABLE MY_USER;

CREATE TABLE MY_USER (
  user_ID int NOT NULL,
  nick varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  date_of_registration date DEFAULT current_date,
  first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(255),
  email varchar(255) UNIQUE, 
  age int NOT NULL,
  user_location varchar(255),
  finished_adventures int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE MY_CHARACTER (
  character_ID int NOT NULL,
  owner_ID int REFERENCES MY_USER(user_ID),
  char_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  race varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  char_class varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  char_rank int NOT NULL,
  hp int NOT NULL,
  status int NOT NULL,
  CHECK (char_rank <= 99 AND char_rank >= 0),
  CHECK (hp <= 100 AND hp >= 0),
  CHECK (status <= 1 AND status >= 0),
  PRIMARY KEY(character_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE EQUIPMENT (
  equipment_ID int NOT NULL,
  owner_ID int REFERENCES MY_CHARACTER(character_ID),
  equipment_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  equipment_type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  attack int NOT NULL,
  defense int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(equipment_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DUNGEON (
  dungeon_ID int NOT NULL,
  dungeon_location varchar(255),
  dungeon_difficulty int NOT NULL,
  goal varchar(2500),
  status int NOT NULL,
  dungeon_creator_ID int REFERENCES AUTHOR(author_ID),
  CHECK (dungeon_difficulty <= 5 AND dungeon_difficulty >= 0),
  PRIMARY KEY(dungeon_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ADVENTURE (
  adventure_ID int NOT NULL,
  adventure_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  adventure_location varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  adventure_difficulty int NOT NULL,
  participant_ID int REFERENCES CHARACTER_GROUP(chargroup_ID),
  adventure_goal varchar(2500),
  creator_ID int REFERENCES AUTHOR(author_ID),
  PRIMARY KEY (adventure_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_GROUP (
  chargroup_ID int NOT NULL,
  group_participant_ID int NOT NULL REFERENCES MY_CHARACTER(character_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CAVE (
  game_room_ID int NOT NULL,
  cave_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  dm_ID int REFERENCES MY_USER(user_ID),
  dungeon_sub int REFERENCES DUNGEON(dungeon_ID),
  adventure_sub int REFERENCES ADVENTURE(adventure_ID),
  cave_creation_date date DEFAULT current_date NOT NULL,
  playing_group int REFERENCES CHARACTER_GROUP(chargroup_ID),
  PRIMARY KEY(game_room_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE AUTHOR (
  author_ID int NOT NULL,
  email varchar (255) UNIQUE,
  nick varchar (255) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE BASIC_USER(
  basic_ID int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES MY_USER(user_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ADMIN_USER(
  admin_ID int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES MY_USER(user_ID),
  permissions int NOT NULL,
  specialization varchar(255)
);
```

Errors:

> Table BASIC_USER dropped.
>
> Table ADMIN_USER dropped.
>
> Table EQUIPMENT dropped.
>
> Error starting at line : 4 in command - DROP TABLE CAVE Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>
> Error starting at line : 5 in command - DROP TABLE DUNGEON Error
>   report - SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>
> Error starting at line : 6 in command - DROP TABLE ADVENTURE Error
>   report - SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Table AUTHOR dropped.
>
> Table CHARACTER_GROUP dropped.
>
> Table MY_CHARACTER dropped.
>
> Table MY_USER dropped.
>
> Table MY_USER created.
>
> Table MY_CHARACTER created.
>
> Table EQUIPMENT created.
>
> Error starting at line : 50 in command - CREATE TABLE DUNGEON (
>   dungeon_ID int NOT NULL,   dungeon_location varchar(255),
>   dungeon_difficulty int NOT NULL,   goal varchar(2500),   status int
>   NOT NULL,   dungeon_creator_ID int REFERENCES AUTHOR(author_ID),
>   CHECK (dungeon_difficulty <= 5 AND dungeon_difficulty >= 0),   PRIMARY
>   KEY(dungeon_ID) ) Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view
>   does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>
> Error starting at line : 61 in command - CREATE TABLE ADVENTURE (
>   adventure_ID int NOT NULL,   adventure_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   adventure_location varchar(255) NOT NULL,   adventure_difficulty int
>   NOT NULL,   participant_ID int REFERENCES
>   CHARACTER_GROUP(chargroup_ID),   adventure_goal varchar(2500),
>   creator_ID int REFERENCES AUTHOR(author_ID),   PRIMARY KEY
>   (adventure_ID) ) Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view
>   does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Table CHARACTER_GROUP created.
>
> Error starting at line : 77 in command - CREATE TABLE CAVE (
>   game_room_ID int NOT NULL,   cave_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,   dm_ID
>   int REFERENCES MY_USER(user_ID),   dungeon_sub int REFERENCES
>   DUNGEON(dungeon_ID),   adventure_sub int REFERENCES
>   ADVENTURE(adventure_ID),   cave_creation_date date DEFAULT
>   current_date NOT NULL,   playing_group int REFERENCES
>   CHARACTER_GROUP(chargroup_ID),   PRIMARY KEY(game_room_ID) ) Error
>   report - SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Table AUTHOR created.
>
> Table BASIC_USER created.
>
> Table ADMIN_USER created.

Any idea what's the cause of this "table or view does not exist" error?

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal example, removing everything else from your code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a foreign key without defining the referenced table first. So, all you need to do is reorder the DDLs in such a way that all the table defined before being referenced. SQL doesn't directly allow forward referencing.

There can be a scenario where you might have to define a circular dependency. So, it's better to define the all tables first and then define apply constraints.

Another alternative, as suggested by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller), is to use `CREATE SCHEMA` statement which lets create multiple tables and views and perform multiple grants in your own schema in a single transaction and use forward referencing.

```
DROP TABLE BASIC_USER;
DROP TABLE ADMIN_USER;
DROP TABLE EQUIPMENT;
DROP TABLE CAVE;
DROP TABLE DUNGEON;
DROP TABLE ADVENTURE;
DROP TABLE AUTHOR;
DROP TABLE CHARACTER_GROUP;
DROP TABLE MY_CHARACTER;
DROP TABLE MY_USER;



CREATE TABLE AUTHOR (
  author_ID int NOT NULL,
  email varchar (255) UNIQUE,
  nick varchar (255) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE MY_USER (
  user_ID int NOT NULL,
  nick varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  date_of_registration date DEFAULT current_date,
  first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(255),
  email varchar(255) UNIQUE, 
  age int NOT NULL,
  user_location varchar(255),
  finished_adventures int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_ID)
);



CREATE TABLE BASIC_USER(
  basic_ID int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES MY_USER(user_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ADMIN_USER(
  admin_ID int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES MY_USER(user_ID),
  permissions int NOT NULL,
  specialization varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE MY_CHARACTER (
  character_ID int NOT NULL,
  owner_ID int REFERENCES MY_USER(user_ID),
  char_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  race varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  char_class varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  char_rank int NOT NULL,
  hp int NOT NULL,
  status int NOT NULL,
  CHECK (char_rank <= 99 AND char_rank >= 0),
  CHECK (hp <= 100 AND hp >= 0),
  CHECK (status <= 1 AND status >= 0),
  PRIMARY KEY(character_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE EQUIPMENT (
  equipment_ID int NOT NULL,
  owner_ID int REFERENCES MY_CHARACTER(character_ID),
  equipment_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  equipment_type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  attack int NOT NULL,
  defense int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(equipment_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DUNGEON (
  dungeon_ID int NOT NULL,
  dungeon_location varchar(255),
  dungeon_difficulty int NOT NULL,
  goal varchar(2500),
  status int NOT NULL,
  dungeon_creator_ID int REFERENCES AUTHOR(author_ID),
  CHECK (dungeon_difficulty <= 5 AND dungeon_difficulty >= 0),
  PRIMARY KEY(dungeon_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_GROUP (
  chargroup_ID int NOT NULL,
  group_participant_ID int NOT NULL REFERENCES MY_CHARACTER(character_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ADVENTURE (
  adventure_ID int NOT NULL,
  adventure_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  adventure_location varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  adventure_difficulty int NOT NULL,
  participant_ID int REFERENCES CHARACTER_GROUP(chargroup_ID),
  adventure_goal varchar(2500),
  creator_ID int REFERENCES AUTHOR(author_ID),
  PRIMARY KEY (adventure_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CAVE (
  game_room_ID int NOT NULL,
  cave_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  dm_ID int REFERENCES MY_USER(user_ID),
  dungeon_sub int REFERENCES DUNGEON(dungeon_ID),
  adventure_sub int REFERENCES ADVENTURE(adventure_ID),
  cave_creation_date date DEFAULT current_date NOT NULL,
  playing_group int REFERENCES CHARACTER_GROUP(chargroup_ID),
  PRIMARY KEY(game_room_ID)
);
```

Comment: As an alternative to re-ordering the DDL it's also possible to define multiple tables at once using [`CREATE SCHEMA`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9107192/409172).